# UISearchResultsUpdating getting crash when it s called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am using Apple [CATALOG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Objective_C_UICatalog_AAPLSearchShowResultsInSourceViewController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-Objective_C_UICatalog_AAPLSearchShowResultsInSourceViewController_h-DontLinkElementID_38) Source code for displaying search bar controller on navigation controller.

It does load, but when i click on search, it get crash due to **UISearchResultsUpdating**-

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AAPLSearchBarEmbeddedInNavigationBarViewController updateSearchResultsForSearchController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15db8ab0'

Suggest me the reason for crash.

code for crash -

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

  if (!searchController.active) {
    return;
  }

self.filterString = searchController.searchBar.text;
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  i checked it s not due to connection it is due to UISearchResultsUpdating

Comment: please ref this [link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html), it may be support you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is self-explanative. You're crash is not on this method, but in place where you call it. You're sending message to a wrong object.